# Open Book To, At, On

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question about the prepositions to use with verb and adjective "*open*":

> 1a. He opened the book ***at*** page 10.
>   1b. "He opened the book ***on*** page 10.
>   1c. "He opened the book ***to*** page 10.
>
> 2a. The book fell open ***at*** page 10.
>   2b. The book fell open ***on*** page 10.
>   2c. The book fell open ***to*** page 10.

How are 1a, 1b, and 1c different? How are 2a, 2b, and 2c different?  Are some of them wrong?

Comment: Usually "to" is used.

Comment: This probably needs to be more specific.  Your examples all deal with books, but there are special uses for open at/to/on for books vs doors vs windows vs etc.  Do you only want to know about the usage with books?

Comment: @JasonPatterson  Thank you for your reply!  I just want to know more about the preposition usage with books only.  The question might get too big if other stuff is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1a - *at* is a preposition, and "page 10" is an object, not a place.
1b - A better usage of *on* is:
`He opened the book up on page 10.`
1c - Probably the most correct.

2a - same as 1a.
2b - This usage makes it seem like the book was open and fell on page 10.
2c - Seems okay.

Comment: Your numbers don't match up with those in the question. Please double-check.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock sorry - fixed

Answer (score 0):

None of them is "wrong", nor really "different" in meaning, but 1(c) and 2(a) are the preferred expressions (in AmE).

I can't explain why. But here is some confirmation.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opened+the+book+at+%C2%A0page%2C+opened+the+book+on+page%2C+opened+the+book+to+page&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copened%20the%20book%20at%20page%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copened%20the%20book%20to%20page%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=book+fell+open+at%2C+book+fell+open+on%2Cbook+fell+open+to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbook%20fell%20open%20at%3B%2Cc0